# I need help with how to prove these two equalities hold true?

Tags: general-topology

I'm writing the two theorems here and including images of the proofs, with the equalities I'm having trouble proving for myself indicated. Thanks for your help.

Theorem 1 (e): If $f:X \to Y$ is continuous and $Z$ is a subspace of  $Y$ containing the image set $f(X)$, then the function $g:X \to Z$ is continuous.

Theorem 2 (f): The map $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if $X$ can be written as the union of open sets $U_{\alpha}$ such that $f|U_{\alpha}$ ($f$ restricted to $U_{\alpha})$ is continuous for each $\alpha.$

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you are asking?

Comment: I need a little explanation on how they're true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $B\subset U$, it's obviously true that $g^{-1}(B)\subset f^{-1}(U)$. Now, if $x\in f^{-1}(U)$, then $f(x)\in U$. Since $f(x)\in f(X)\subset Z$, we also have $f(x)\in U\bigcap Z=B$. Then $x\in g^{-1}(B)$, since $g(x)=f(x)$. So we also have $f^{-1}(U)\subset g^{-1}(B)$

For the second equality, if $x\in f^{-1}(V)$, then $x\in U_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$, since $\bigcup_{\alpha}U_\alpha=X$. It follows that $x\in \bigcup_{\alpha} f^{-1}(V)\bigcap U_{\alpha}$, so $f^{-1}(V)\subset\bigcup_{\alpha} f^{-1}(V)\bigcap U_{\alpha}$. Now, suppose $x\in \bigcup_{\alpha} f^{-1}(V)\bigcap U_{\alpha}$. Then we have for some $\alpha$: $x\in f^{-1}(V)\bigcap U_{\alpha}\subset f^{-1}(V)$, so $\bigcup_{\alpha} f^{-1}(V)\bigcap U_{\alpha}\subset f^{-1}(V)$.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** $\displaystyle g^{-1}(B) = g^{-1} (Z \cap U) = g^{-1}(Z) \cap g^{-1}(U)$ and since $Z$ contains $f(X)$ this is equal to $ \displaystyle X \cap g^{-1}(U) = g^{-1} (U) = f^{-1}(U)$

**(2)** $ \displaystyle \bigcup_\alpha(f^{-1}(V) \cap U_\alpha) = f^{-1}(V) \cap ( \bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha) = f^{-1}(V) \cap X = f^{-1}(V)$

Comment: How can I make the $\cup_\alpha$ bigger ?

Comment: `\bigcup` $\bigcup$

Comment: @StefanHamcke Thanks